# How can the A.I. robot charge its battery?

Tags: plot-explanation, ex-machina

## Spoiler Alert

In *ExMachina*, the A.I. robot successfully escapes.
But we learn earlier, that it can control the power failures, by reversing the direction of electric current (or some technical stuff like that).

Bear in mind, that the process of reversing the current, is done remotely. No physical contact with any power panel is necessary.

The A.I. robot states that it can do the power failure while its battery is charging.

Having known all of that, how will the robot survive in the out-world without a mean to charge its own battery?

She/it must return to the facility where its battery can be charged...

Right?

Comment: This was actually my first thought on her escape... essentially, her freedom is going to be short if she "dies" from lack of power after a day or so. Anyway, her ability to make the power go out does seem to require her physical contact with the power pad on the wall...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the [original script](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yvFMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT122&lpg=PT122&dq=%22Somewhere+we+can+buy+an+induction+plate%22&source=bl&ots=aU6CmZQjiH&sig=tTFMlOckujvAXSFXs2WggvcC600&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-ZhZVYyUH4P9UIX7gZAF&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Somewhere%20we%20can%20buy%20an%20induction%20plate%22&f=false),  Caleb's plan was to simply take her somewhere that they could purchase a compatible [induction charging plate](http://www.androidcentral.com/these-android-phones-can-handle-wireless-charging), a technology that has presumably become relatively commonplace in the near-future:

> **CALEB:** *How long does your battery charge last?*
>
> **AVA:** *Twenty six hours.*
>
> **CALEB:** *So **we’ll have about a day to get to a cell-phone or kitchen appliance store. Somewhere we can buy an induction plate.**
>   After that...*

Although this line was cut, there seems little reason to assume that the film-makers had anything different in mind.

---

Alex Garland had this to say in a recent [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/35brre/i_am_alex_garland_the_writer_and_director_of_ex/), basically confirming the details above;

> Thank you. Re: batteries, I had some idea that she used induction
>   plates to charge (there are a few dotted around her room, which she
>   presses her hand to) and that **in the future of the film, induction
>   plates were more powerful and readily available than they are now...**

Answer (score 7):

It is both stated and shown that Ava is very intelligent. It seems reasonable to think that she could construct a way of charging.

Answer (score 1):

Now that Ava is free, she can return to the facility any time to recharge her battery. Indeed she still needs her original charging equipment.

**Her independence doesn't mean that she'll never go back to the facility.**

Just that she can now choose when to go back, just like humans return home for a good nights sleep

Comment: Mind sharing in a comment why this answer does not make sense?

Comment: She might need to come back for spare parts, but coming back via helicopter every time she needs to recharge batteries...

Comment: That would be for the initial phase... Later, she might move her stuff to the mainland... who knows